# How to link Google Play console with Google Pub/Sub Topics for real-time notification?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-play-console

I have to implement real-time google developer notifications. For that purpose, I have to use Google Pub/Sub. There are multiple steps:

1. Create topics and subscriptions. (This part is done)
2. Link Google Pub/Sub topic to Google Play console. (This part is not working)

The error says that either topics name is wrong or there are some issues in the service account.
But I have granted all the necessary permissions to the service account. The necessary permissions were the "Pub/Sub publisher" permission. It is granted but still getting same error.

I am following this link for that purpose.
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#create-sub

The screen shots are attached

[Screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtZhN.png)
[Screen shot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17bJ0.png)

Comment: Kindly remind that you should never include personal identifiable information in the screenshots that you share.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: I've removed a screenshot here which *may* contain PII. It's not clear if every one of the email addresses shown are fake, or if some/all are real. If they are all fake, then feel free to add it back in, with a comment that the email addresses are fake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the service account you are using is not exactly the same service account in the link you shared.

Try using and granting the permissions to the service account:

`google-play-developer-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: It was just for example.The main thing was permission, which we set.

Comment: Does any one explain pub/sub pricing?